# HTTPSConnectionPool(host='ec2-...', port=8080): Max retries exceeded with url: /v1/getinfo (Caused by SSLError(CertificateError

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh, ssl-certificate, bitcoin

I am running the SSL error (HTTPSConnectionPool(host='ec2-aa-aaa-aaa-aa.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com', port=8080): Max retries exceeded with url: /v1/getinfo (Caused by SSLError(CertificateError("hostname 'ec2-aa-aaa-aa-aa.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com' doesn't match either of 'ip-bbb-bb-bb-bb', 'localhost', 'unix'...) and haven't been able to find a solution myself.
Actually the ip-bbb-bb-bb-bb mentioned in the ip that cannot be found is my private ip of the EC" instance, and the ec2-aa-aaa-aaa-aa.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com' is the public one.

Some details about my EC2 instance. I am running a Bitcoin and LND node there and they are working properly. However when I try to access them from an API running locally I get this error.

This are the security rules for my instance (I know maybe not the safest but I was trying to see what could cause the error)

```
–   sgr-0b6e4646f963ac348   All         All     0.0.0.0/0   
–   sgr-0c9433a6bdbc5c986   8333        TCP     ::/0    
–   sgr-0ab3df01e90304321   8333        TCP     0.0.0.0/0       
–   sgr-002bc487360643667   443         TCP     0.0.0.0/0   
–   sgr-08bad3cd41c9d3365   80          TCP     0.0.0.0/0   
–   sgr-005fa2007f73f3466   28333       TCP     0.0.0.0/0   
–   sgr-0fba32539580d3071   0 - 65535   TCP     0.0.0.0/0
–   sgr-092c6691e0dbdf9d3   All         ICMP    0.0.0.0/0
–   sgr-000bdb5bee77e7314   8000        TCP     0.0.0.0/0   
–   sgr-0112ef3fdd16c2b75   22  TCP 0.0.0.0/0
```

I am connecting to the instance from my django API through ssh.I am posting the code below:

```
import boto3
import paramiko
import os
import base64, codecs

# Define the instance's ID and the key pair name
instance_id = "<i-blahblahblah>"
key_name = "<some_keyname>"

# Create a session using your AWS credentials
session = boto3.Session(
    aws_access_key_id="<some_access_key_is>",
    aws_secret_access_key="<some_aws_secret_access_key>",
    region_name="eu-central-1",
)

# Use the session to create an EC2 client
ec2 = session.client("ec2")

# Retrieve the IP address of the instance
instance = ec2.describe_instances(InstanceIds=[instance_id])["Reservations"][0][
    "Instances"
][0]
ip_address = instance["PublicIpAddress"]
print(ip_address)
# Use the session to create a SSM client
ssm = session.client("ssm")

# Start a session to the instance using SSM
response = ssm.start_session(Target=instance_id)

# Use paramiko to SSH into the instance
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
key_name = "<path_to_key>"
ssh.connect(ip_address, username="ubuntu", key_filename=f"{key_name}.pem")

# Execute the command to retrieve the environment variable
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("echo $VARNAME")
my_variable = stdout.read().strip().decode()
# Read the output of the command
sftp_client = ssh.open_sftp()
remote_path = "/home/ubuntu/.lnd/data/chain/bitcoin/mainnet/admin.macaroon"
remote_file = sftp_client.open(remote_path, "r")

# Read contents of file
file_contents = remote_file.read()
encoded_hex = codecs.encode(file_contents, "hex")
encoded_string = encoded_hex.decode("utf-8")


# Now you can use the decoded string in your API
print(encoded_string)

# Get the path to the certificate file on the EC2 instance
remote_cert_file = "/home/ubuntu/.lnd/tls.cert"
# Transfer the certificate file from the EC2 instance to the local machine
local_cert_file = "tls.cert"
sftp = ssh.open_sftp()
sftp.get(remote_cert_file, local_cert_file)

# Specify the path to the local certificate file for SSL verification
cert_file_path = os.path.abspath(local_cert_file)
print(cert_file_path)
sftp.close()
# Close file and SFTP client
remote_file.close()

stdin.close()
# Close the SSH connection and SSM session
ssh.close()
ssm.terminate_session(SessionId=response["SessionId"])
response = {"file_contents": file_contents}
```

I would really appreciate any help. I have been struggling for almost a week trying things but nothing works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I needed to generate a new tls.cert for my lnd node that point to the local host as well as to the aws endpoint. I used the command below:

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout /home/ec2-user/.lnd/tls.key -out /home/ec2-user/.lnd/tls.cert -days 365 -nodes -subj '/CN=127.0.0.1' -extensions SAN -config <(cat /etc/pki/tls/openssl.cnf <(printf "[SAN]\nsubjectAltName=DNS:localhost,DNS:unix,DNS:unixpacket,DNS:bufconn,IP:127.0.0.1,IP:<aws_private_ip>,IP:<aws_public_ip>,DNS:ec2-a-aaa-aa-aa.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com"))
```

and the convert the .cert file into .pem file

`openssl x509 -in tls.cert -out tls.pem -outform PEM`
Then copy the tls.pem in my ca-certification directory and then run:

`sudo update-ca-trust`
And voilaa, it works